# Disable "-mp4-image" screenshots from appearing in Media?

Tags: customization

If I upload a video in the mp4 format Wordpress automatically creates an image called Filename-mp4-image.jpg which is a screenshot of the uploaded video.
This is fine, but what I don't like is that when I select an image in a custom post type (where images is only allowed) the screenshot shows up too.

Is it possible to disable the screenshots from showing up in the image media browser? And only use the screenshot for the file itself (when you look at the MP4 file under Media)?

Thank you!

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour before. As far as I can tell WordPress doesn't create thumbnail images for videos. If your site's doing this then it's probably a plugin, or your theme.

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem was. I uploaded the files via Wordpress at first, then removed them and reuploaded them with FTP. And maybe the screenshot became visible this time?

Comment: Only if a plugin or theme did it. That's not how WordPress works on its own. Uploading anything via FTP will not add to or change anything in the media library.